# create_wall_timer(): monotonic clock?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the timer created by [create_wall_timer()](https://docs.ros2.org/beta3/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1node_1_1Node.html#a1a727c1777f045074e13b2cbc6e9b0e3) monotonic? i.e., guaranteed never to jump backwards (or forwards) due to midnight, daylight savings time, user changing the system clock, clock adjustments via NTP, etc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384178/create_wall_timer():-monotonic-clock?/) by [high12noon](https://answers.ros.org/users/79729/high12noon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [rclcpp::timer](https://docs.ros2.org/beta3/api/rclcpp/namespacerclcpp_1_1timer.html#a669efd73299d53391a65dee9643965e0) docs, `std::chrono::steady_clock` is used,

```
using   WallTimer = GenericTimer< CallbackType, std::chrono::steady_clock >
```

Quoting from [std::chrono::steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) docs,

> Class std::chrono::steady_clock
> represents a monotonic clock. The time
> points of this clock cannot decrease
> as physical time moves forward and the
> time between ticks of this clock is
> constant. This clock is not related to
> wall clock time (for example, it can
> be time since last reboot), and is
> most suitable for measuring intervals.

So to answer your question, **Yes, it is guaranteed never to jump backwards** (or forwards) due to midnight, daylight savings time, user changing the system clock, clock adjustments via NTP, etc

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2021-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-08-10**:
And adding a small note for anyone who is curious, from [std::chrono::duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) docs,

```
Note: each of the predefined duration types up to hours covers a range of at least ±292 years.
```

So overflow also won't be an issue, at least in our lifetime